# How to make a text reverse using discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

How would one make a text reverse using discord.py?

```
>Example: >reverse hi

>Output: ih
```

Something like that,  any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to  stackoverflow! The next time you ask a question, please include code that you have tried. I already have this code, so I'll give this to you and explain in the code comments.

```py
@client.command()
async def reverse(ctx, *, arg="A normal sentence"): # if user gives no arg, aka just >reverse
    await ctx.message.delete() # deletes original command message
    await ctx.send(arg[::-1]) # sends the backward sentence, in this case: ecnetnes lamron A
```